# Certain js File Not Working in Drupal

Tags: javascript, drupal

I'm trying to render one div before another.

I've tested the js on my local machine to make sure it works by creating a simple page. The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="QWERTY">
        <div class="content">   
            <div class="field-name-field-image-one">IMAGE</div>
            <div class="body">BODY</div>
        </div>
    </div>       
<script>$('.content .body').insertBefore('.content .field-name-field-image-one'); // check before() examples</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've added the following code to a js file on my Drupal site:

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {

    $('.content .body').insertBefore('.content .field-name-field-image-one'); // check before() examples

})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

My .info file links to the js and it is loading. Other elements that require javascript are working too. I've even tried adding the script in the html.tpl file, but that did not work either.

The divs I am trying to affect are nested deep within the html markup, and have several classes applied to them, compared to the simple version I have made. Could that be the reason?  Am I not being specific enough?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some help, I've updated it to the following, and it works:

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {
  $(function() {
    $('.content .body').insertBefore('.content .field-name-field-image-one'); // check before() examples
  });

})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Javascript to change the order of fields in a content type.

If you're using Drupal 7, go to Home » Administration » Structure (/admin/structure/types) and click "manage display" next to the content type you want to change. You can now drag and drop the fields to change their display order for each view mode (e.g., Default, Teaser).

If you really want to use Javascript to do this, Drupal 7 uses a special syntax.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.custom_moveimage = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.content .body').insertBefore('.content .field-name-field-image-one');
    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```

The Drupal documentation has [more information](https://drupal.org/node/171213) about this.